# The name 'ID1' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Apparently I am doing something wrong when I am trying to connect the ID1 between the two files below and I am running out of ideas right now.

**How do I fix the error:
The name 'ID1' does not exist in the current context**

In "**PrintExtraInfo.aspx**"

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="ContactRightTD">

            <span class="minititle">ID1</span>
            <div class="divider3">
            </div>

            <asp:Label ID="ID1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
            <div class="divider3">
            </div>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

In "**PrintExtraInfo.aspx.cs**":

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
    {
        email = Request.QueryString["m"].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            DataSet ds = MySQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM auctioncartechspec");
            DataRow row;
            if ((row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]) != null)
            {
                ID1.Text = row["ID"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: label id doesn't find. Check your lable id .

Comment: Try using `id` rather than `ID` as the attribute name in your HTML...

Comment: Is the `.Designer.cs` file associated with that page up-to-date? Does it contain an `ID1` field?

Comment: This might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y81z8326(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: There are no problems with this implementation. Can you provide the whole source code of both files?

Comment: I can not provide the whole source code due to a contract I am under. But I will try out all the other things and return with my results!

Answer (score 1):

Actually this implementation worked once I restarted my computer for the third time, sorry for the inconvenience.